# What does the expression : Select `(column1|column2|column3)?+.+` from Table in SQL means?

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, regex-group

I am trying to convert a SQL Code into Pyspark SQL.
While selecting the columns from a table , the Select Statement has something as below :

```
Select a.`(column1|column2|column3)?+.+`,trim(column c)  from Table a;
```

I would like to understand what

```
a.`(column1|column2|column3)?+.+`
```

expression resolves to and what it actually implies?  How to address this while converting the sql into pyspark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a way of selecting certain column names using regexps. That regex matches (and excludes) the columns `column1`, `column2` or `column3`.

It is the Spark's equivalent of the Hive's [Quoted Identifiers](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties#ConfigurationProperties-hive.support.quoted.identifiers). See also [Spark's documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select.html).

Be aware that, for enabling this behavior, it is first necessary to run the following command:

```
spark.sql("SET spark.sql.parser.quotedRegexColumnNames=true").show(false)
```